# Chrome inspector keeps opening and focusing on console when editing css

Tags: inspector

This only happens sometimes but won't stop until I restart my computer. I will be editing a stylesheet writing some css and after I type 1 or 2 the console opens is focused on and starts typing in there. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to happen to me when I am using chrome. It just opens the console and "Freezes". This is what worked for me.

Open the console. Click on the sources tab[image: This is the sources tab]

Then you are going to check at the far bottom-right corner for event listener breakpoints.
You will see a long list of DOM events eg click,keyboard ie.
[image]

If any of the events is checked, uncheck them.

If it still pops that screen, press F8 and then CTRL+F8.
That fixes the problem. Hope this helps.